# Flutter NFC Card read /write issue with nfc_manger Package

Tags: flutter, nfc

I am looking for some help to solve this problem.
I'm using nfc_manager package to read and write nfc cards in my flutter project.
it works fine. But several times when I writing cards I got an error. which is "ndef" is null and popup an error which I put ("Tag is not ndef writable.")
and after that I couldn't read and write any cards.
In that time I have to restart the device and then it works fine.
Anyone have any ideas??The code is as follows

```
if (await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable()) {
  await NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
  print("available");
}

await NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
  var ndef = Ndef.from(tag);
  if (ndef == null || !ndef.isWritable) {                         // ndef is null(error is here)
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
    print("failed");
    var baseDialog = BaseAlertDialog(
      title: "Warning",
      content: "Tag is not ndef writable.",
      backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade300,
      yesOnPressed: () {
        _isPrintPressed = false;
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      yes: "OK",
    );
    showDialog(
        context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) => baseDialog);
    return;
  }
  NdefMessage ndefMessage = null;
  try {
    ndefMessage = await ndef.read();
  } catch (e) {}

 if (await _validateTag(ndefMessage)  || ndefMessage == null  ) {
 // then go ahead
```

Comment: You need to specify what hardware/os version you are seeing this problem on because NFC implementation are very different between iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand how it works under the hood, but i got the same problem with you when writing and reading rfid tag on flutter. The only solution for me is changing to another library like [Flutter_nfc_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit) which has less frequency of nullable while writing on tag. Wish someone can explain this error.